# Where are my node scripts from package.json?

Tags: node.js

Every package.json file has a section with scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Where can I find these scripts on my computer to inspect what they do exactly?

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts

Comment: Source: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts

Comment: hm, I am really looking for the location on the hard drive. Not just an explanation for a specific package.json

Comment: Usually `node_modules/react-scripts/bin`

Comment: Hm, so my specific problem was that I wanted to look into the script "npm run start:prod" for a library called NestJS. For React, these scripts seem easy to find. I can't find them in the NestJS Library however. So, I was wondering how to find them, since node also needs some kind of path to them.

Comment: But thanks for the answers so far